# Best way to automate tasks in a browser

Tags: browser, scripting, automation, task, autohotkey

I want to automate several tasks that include copying numbers from a local list, then pasting each one in a certain box in a web page, then do several clicks on boxes that pop up in the browser, lastly, to copy some text from that page and paste it as the name of a file we save from that web page.

Is the best way to acheive that is with AutoHotKey or is there a better way?

Comment: What's wrong with [the solutions](https://www.google.com/#q=web+page+fill+form+automatically) from the first page on google?

Comment: @wOxxOm it's not exactly a form fill, there are other steps too and also what we fill varies, each time it's a different number.

Comment: In that case your description is too generic and the answer might be `write an extension or a userscript`.

Comment: @wOxxOm you mean a userscript that will run with greasmonkey?

Comment: Not necessarily. Chrome can run userscripts [natively](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts), just name the file as something.user.js and drag'n'drop onto an opened chrome://extensions page.

Comment: @wOxxOm is it called simply `userscript`? Do you know of a good beginners site with examples or tutorials? Is there an IDE or compiler for that?

Comment: dont know about usercripts, but ahk can surely do what you need. it's even got features like image recognition, window control detection and sending text into fields in inactive windows

Comment: AHK won't be able to easily select input fields by their names. However it can be used if it's okay to blindly send mouseclicks to certain positions or use {Tab} keys. Userscript is a javascript code with a [special header](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block), so just use any tutorial on javascript.

Comment: If you use IE, Autohotkey can fully control any webpage just like javascript

Comment: Added benefit of using Autohotkey over userscripts is that you can also easily automate other window tasks not just webpages within the browser

Comment: @blackholyman does AHK have an IE addon or something?

Comment: Post'ed my answer as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the component object model is built-in so you can automate the DOM just like javascript using IE's Built-in methods

A tutorial http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/47052-basic-webpage-controls-with-javascript-com-tutorial/#entry293231